# How to close a dialog window in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I have viewcontroller A and on click of button, i have opened a another viewcontroller with presentation style as Form sheet. In second view controller which is opened have two buttons. Now, when these buttons are clicked, this second view controller should go away and next view controller should open on top of view controller A. But when i am trying below, another view controllers are opening up inside the dialog 
i don't know how to unwind this segue and call another scene together.

Answer (score 0):

Nitya, did you try the following piece of code to dismiss current view controller. Use it in the IBAction of the button where you want to dismiss the viewController:-

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I have already tried this. It will dismiss the dialog window but you will not go to next screen, like view controller. I want when the dialog window is closed,  user should go to next view controller.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Sorry, I'm new to iOS. Tried to help. I prefer using views rather than viewControllers in such cases. You can easily hide/unhide views and can easily load view of any controller inside another uiview.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a root viewcontroller A with a button. If you tap that button, an other viewcontroller (let's name it B) is presented by A as a form sheet. B has two buttons and if you tap one of those buttons, B should be dismissed and **after** a different viewcontroller (let's say C) shold be presented by A.

Apple don't really recommend this kind of workflow, nevertheless it is possible to implement it. You may shold consider to use navigation controller or master-detail controller instead of this. But if you stick to your original idea here are some possible implementations:

1.
If you are using a storyboard and the button on B triggers an unwind segue to A then you can add this to the end of the unwind seque action:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueThatPresentsC" sender:nil];
});
```

2.
If you present your viewcontrollers programmatically then:
Before you present B from A you can configure a button of B so that ist target is A and and its action is a method defined in A:

```
- (void) dismissAndPresentC {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self presentViewController:instanceOfC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

This second is maybe a bit smaller hack, but still a confusing concept.